# How to simulate finfet in ltspice?

Tags: ltspice, symbol, finfet

I need to compare planar MOS transistor and FinFET for a project. But there is no inbuilt symbol for FinFET in LTspice IV. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The model is more important than the symbol by a mile.

Answer (score 2):

First find a model: an example of a Finfet model can be found [here](http://ptm.asu.edu/latest.html).

Then you need to [import the model in to LT spice](http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_4.htm).

Remember spice is only for modeling circuits, it doesn't always reflect what happens int the real world. Spice is really only a text file, graphical packages only generate the spice netlist, it is important to understand the spice code. In Lt spice this can be located under view->spice netlist